# Mongoose find anywhere inside document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, underscore.js

i need to find record matching userId. the userId can be in any level of document. 
It can be in parent level or it can be inside friends array.

```
[{
    "_id": "543357620c9af6066e689713",
    "createdDate": "2014-10-06 08:00 pm",
    "cancle": false,
    "eventDate": "2014/12/12",
    "eventstatus": true,
    "location": "chennai",
    "userId": "54334def7e85de48638d1069",
    "createdBy": "four",
    "eventName": "jamba",
    "__v": 0,
    "friends": []
},
{
    "_id": "543356fe0c9af6066e68970c",
    "createdDate": "2014-10-06 07:59 pm",
    "cancle": false,
    "eventDate": "2014/12/12",
    "eventstatus": true,
    "location": "chennai",
    "userId": "54310801e2659ecc3650100b",
    "createdBy": "one",
    "eventName": "tea ",
    "__v": 0,
    "friends": [
        {
            "userId": "54310814e2659ecc3650100c",
            "userName": "two",
            "phoneNumber": "22222222"
        },
        {
            "userId": "54310945e2659ecc3650100d",
            "userName": "three",
            "phoneNumber": "33333333"
        },
        {
            "userId": "54334def7e85de48638d1069",
            "userName": "four",
            "phoneNumber": "44444444"
        }
    ]
}]
```

i am trying for long time. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: after trying for a long time, may you can actually show what have you tried?

Comment: i tried,        Events.find().where('friends.userId').equals(req.params.userId).exec(); Events.find({ 'friends.userId': req.params.userId }).exec();  I also tried underscore filter. nothing works :(

Comment: 1. get the `friends`. 2. Iterate over `friends` array with `length > 0` to get `userId`. 3. now find user with matching `userId`. **`Hint`**: You  might need to use nested queries. This `might` be possible with Aggregation but i don't know that much about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `$or` operator. Also, you don't need to iterate to query for elements within an array. Assuming your collection is named `Events`:

```
Events.find({
    $or: [
        { _id: req.params.userId },
        { 'friends.userId': req.params.userId }
    ]
}).exec();
```